# Java NIO.2 CompletetionHandler not reaching

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous, nio2

Java NIO.2 Gurus could anyone explain why this code not working when I'm commenting out the Thread.sleep(...) line.

And what is the elegant way, to tell JVM to proccess asynchronous operations until program finishes?

```
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.CompletionHandler;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            AsynchronousSocketChannel channel = AsynchronousSocketChannel.open();
            channel.connect(new InetSocketAddress("www.yahoo.com", 80),
                    null, new CompletionHandler<Void, Object>() {
                        @Override
                        public void completed(Void result, Object attachment) {
                            System.out.println("Connected");

                            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap("GET http://www.yahoo.com HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n".getBytes());
                            channel.write(buffer, null, new CompletionHandler<Integer, Object>() {
                                @Override
                                public void completed(Integer result, Object attachment) {
                                    System.out.println("Write completed: " + result.toString());

                                    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(23);

                                    channel.read(buffer, null, new CompletionHandler<Integer, Object>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void completed(Integer result, Object attachment) {
                                            System.out.println("Read completed: " + result.toString());
                                            System.out.println(new String(buffer.array()));
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void failed(Throwable exc, Object attachment) {
                                            exc.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    });
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void failed(Throwable exc, Object attachment) {
                                    exc.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            });
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void failed(Throwable exc, Object attachment) {
                            exc.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });

            Thread.sleep(10000);

            channel.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why it isn't working when Thread.sleep(...) is removed:**

The method `connect(SocketAddress remote, A attachment, CompletionHandler<Void,? super A> handler)` creates a new Thread in which he connects and invokes the handler.

So without the delay you are closing the socket before it's connected or all data was transferred.

**How to avoid it**

You have to find a way to wait for the other threads.

For example with [`java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture<V>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html):

```
try {
    CompletableFuture<Boolean> future = new CompletableFuture<Boolean>();

    AsynchronousSocketChannel channel = AsynchronousSocketChannel.open();
    channel.connect(new InetSocketAddress("www.yahoo.com", 80),
            null, new CompletionHandler<Void, Object>() {
                @Override
                public void completed(Void result, Object attachment) {
                    System.out.println("Connected");

                    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap("GET http://www.yahoo.com HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n".getBytes());
                    channel.write(buffer, null, new CompletionHandler<Integer, Object>() {
                        @Override
                        public void completed(Integer result, Object attachment) {
                            System.out.println("Write completed: " + result.toString());

                            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(23);

                            channel.read(buffer, null, new CompletionHandler<Integer, Object>() {
                                @Override
                                public void completed(Integer result, Object attachment) {
                                    System.out.println("Read completed: " + result.toString());
                                    System.out.println(new String(buffer.array()));

                                    // 
                                    future.complete(true);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void failed(Throwable exc, Object attachment) {
                                    exc.printStackTrace();
                                    //
                                    future.complete(false);
                                }
                            });
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void failed(Throwable exc, Object attachment) {
                            exc.printStackTrace();
                            //
                            future.complete(false);
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void failed(Throwable exc, Object attachment) {
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                    //
                    future.complete(false);
                }
            });
    // Wait until the other Threads are finished
    System.out.println("Successs: "+future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
    channel.close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Or in your case you can simply handle the `AsynchronousSocketChannel` this way (without the handlers):

```
    try {
    AsynchronousSocketChannel channel = AsynchronousSocketChannel.open();
    Future<Void> futureConnect = channel.connect(new InetSocketAddress("www.yahoo.com", 80));
    // wait until connected
    futureConnect.get();
    System.out.println("Connected");

    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap("GET http://www.yahoo.com HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n".getBytes());
    Future<Integer> futureWrite = channel.write(buffer);
    // wait until all data is written
    Integer resultWrite = futureWrite.get();
    System.out.println("Write completed: " + resultWrite.toString());

    ByteBuffer bufferRead = ByteBuffer.allocate(23);
    Future<Integer> futureRead = channel.read(bufferRead);
    // wait ...
    Integer resultRead = futureRead.get();
    System.out.println("Read completed: " + resultRead.toString());
    System.out.println(new String(bufferRead.array()));

    // finnished now the channel can be closed
    channel.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```